# How to change the currentFont in a QTextEdit but leaving the formattation - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing a notepad and I've found a problem.
Basically in a QTextEdit I have different text with different point sizes. So if I want to change the font of these ones their point size will reset to the one of the textbox.

I will make an example with images.

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

As you can see I changed the font to times new roman but the point size changed.

This is the code:

```
void MainWindow::on_fontComboBox_currentFontChanged(const QFont &f)
{
    ui->fontComboBox->setFont(f);
    QTextEdit *edit = getTabTextEdit();
    if(ui->tabWidget->currentWidget() == ui->tab_1)
    {
        ui->edit->setCurrentFont(f);
    }
    else
    {
        edit->setCurrentFont(f);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Store the `fontPointSize` before you change fonts and reapply it with `setFontPointSize`. I don't think there is a way to retain the size.

Comment: But then I will get just one point size, while in the screenshot there are two.

Comment: So how can I make this?

Comment: You might have to process the text yourself in the event that fontPointSize and setFontPointSize aren't good enough for you. You could do this either with a QSyntaxHighlighter or by dynamically setting the HTML based on your own rules.